# PHP and MySQL order by karma points

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table named "posts" with columns "karma" and "date".

I want to print the info inside this table in this order: first the most recent posts, but first of all those recent posts, those with higher karma points.

If I order by `date DESC` and then by `karma DESC`, the table will bring me first all those recent posts and then will order by karma, but not necessary will bring me first those more important posts of the day because the order is to print first the most recent posts (ordered by date desc).

But if instead of this, I order my posts by `karma DESC` and then by `date DESC`, the PHP file will print me first all those posts with highest karma points EVER, and then will order by date all those with less karma points.

Can you please suggest me how do I print first all those recent posts with the highest karma?

In resume, I need to print first the most recent posts with higher karma.

Here is some example data:

```
|------------|-------------|
| ID | KARMA |    DATE     |
|------------|-------------|
| 9  |  23   | November 23 |
|------------|-------------|
| 8  |  13   | November 23 |
|------------|-------------|
| 7  |  19   | November 23 |
|------------|-------------|
| 6  |  33   | November 22 |
|------------|-------------|
| 5  |  2    | November 22 |
|------------|-------------|
| 4  |  9    | November 21 |
|------------|-------------|
```

So the post should be printed on the screen in this id order:

- First the best posts of November 23: 9, 7, 8
- Then the best posts of November 22: 6, 5
- Then the best posts of November 21: 4
- and continue....

I've already tried with:

```
ORDER BY posts.date DESC, posts.karma DESC
```

But this obviously causes to show first the most recent posts and then those with higher karma value.

Comment: Please produce re-producible example with sample data. Or at least show us sample data. You can also use tool like  https://www.db-fiddle.com/ .

Comment: What defines the "most recent posts"?

Comment: "If I order by date DESC and then by karma DESC" - this exact thing should work with your example. Why do you feel you're not getting the desired results?

Comment: Look, this is what happens: https://jmp.sh/QOLwnE1 first the most recent post with 0 karma and then the next post but with 2 of karma...

Comment: So you probably have a full date and time in the database, but you only want to sort by date, not the time.

Comment: You have to stop posting links to external sites about errors or whatever and edit your post instead to contain what they were @GuillermoEsquivelObregón Your question is very unclear. Why the "php" tag and where is the code that you tried?

Comment: Sorry, tought that it will be better using images to explain. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY DATE(`date`) DESC, `karma` DESC
```

This query will prioritize `date` field, then `karma` field in ordering. So, the output will be: `9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 4`

Comment: But with this instruction, if a post with 0 of karma was published after a post with 3 of karma..will print first the most recent with karma 0 and then the one with karma 3 wich was published before...

Comment: Look, here is an example of what happens with this instruction: https://jmp.sh/QOLwnE1

Comment: What is the data type of the column `date`? `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: current_timestamp()

Comment: Then query should be `SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY DATE(date) DESC, karma DESC`.

Comment: DATE(date) DESC, karma DESC did'nt worked, my post with 2 of karma went down to fifth place on the timeline: https://jmp.sh/EOCenxF

Comment: Then, please post your *actual data* with timestamp information.

Comment: Thanks! DATE(`date`) DESC, `karma` DESC worked, the problem was in my DB, some MySQL inputs had different date format, soy now is working very well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

        Create table testT (
         ID int, 
         karma varchar(255),
         table_date date 
        );
        INSERT INTO testT (ID, karma, table_date) 
VALUES ("9","23","2020.11.23"),
("8","13","2020.11.23"),
("7","19","2020.11.23"),
("6","33","2020.11.22"),
("5","2","2020.11.22"),
("4","9","2020.11.21");



    ---

    **Query #1**

        Select * FROM testT ORDER BY table_date DESC, karma DESC;

    | ID  | karma | table_date |
    | --- | ----- | ---------- |
    | 9   | 23    | 2020-11-23 |
    | 7   | 19    | 2020-11-23 |
    | 8   | 13    | 2020-11-23 |
    | 6   | 33    | 2020-11-22 |
    | 5   | 2     | 2020-11-22 |
    | 4   | 9     | 2020-11-21 |

    ---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5MHocXkBQDHSwoDpsbvZoo/0)

Comment: This is what whappens with this order by command: https://jmp.sh/QOLwnE1